# Highcharts does not work with wicked_pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web, highcharts, wicked-pdf, lazy-high-charts

I'm trying to generate a PDF report using the Wicked_pdf gem and Highcharts.
I've already tried to set `animation`, `enableMouseTracking` and `shadow` false.
But when wkhtmltopdf tries to generated the PDF files I got an error.

I really don't not what to do, because when I do the same procedure for an HTML, Highcharts renders perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by setting this options:

```
plotOptions:
  line:
    animation: false
    enableMouseTracking: false
    shadow: false
```

Also, don't forget to include JQuery and inline your styles and scripts

Answer (score 4):

Try setting this:

```
series: { 'enableMouseTracking: false, shadow: false, animation: false' : nil}
```

This solution worked for me. I have a pdf view and a html view and implemented solution has:

```
<more highchart options>
...
plotOptions: {
                  line: {
                    marker: {
                      enabled: false
                    },
                    dashStyle: 'ShortDash'
                  },
                  series: { #{request.format == 'pdf' ? 'enableMouseTracking: false, shadow: false, animation: false' : nil} }
                },
...
<more highchart options>
```

Comment: I solved it using the previous version of wkhtmltopdf, the version 0.10.0_rc2-static-amd64. The last version that i was using has some problems when render javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**Try debugging in the [QtWeb browser](http://www.qtweb.net/download.html).**

**Instructions on debugging javascript in Qt [here](http://qtweb.net/pages/ibr9600.html)**

*You may find that your javascript contains unsupported syntax or keywords, which results in the issue as described.*

The Qt WebKit rendering engine that wkhtmltopdf was using doesn't support [ES2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/), so you might have a simple solution like me, which was to replace keywords like `let` and `const`.