# wicked_pdf gem + Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I read some answers, but didnt solve my problem.

Html charts works good, but when I export to PDF with wicked_pdf charts doesnt show.

I set chart options :

```
 plotOptions: {
      series: {
        enableMouseTracking: false,
        shadow: false, 
        animation: false
      }
    },
```

And tried giving javascript delay.

I tried including and not including in my layout the jquery and/or highcharts js files again according to some posts I read.

But nothing is working for me , my wkhtmltopdf library version is :

```
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt)
```

All answers I read are 2+ years old so maybe someone can help me with a newer method.

Comment: Do you see anything on the chart? Like title or legend? If not, then it's rather not a problem of animation. There is a few issues with wicked_pdf and rendering SVG, not necessary connected to the Highcharts library itself, have you checked them? For example [this bug report](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/313).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally solved.

Some steps were not necessary, but I will note it anyways to help the most people :

1.- Change wkhtmltopdf version, I was using 0.12 , now I installed

```
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

This gem works with 0.9 version of wkhtmltopdf

2.- Remove animation and other stuff from Highcharts. Seems like works without it too, buts its better to be sure, I'm testing locally and things like animation increases the risk of not rendering the complete chart in time.

Add this config to charts container file :

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    enableMouseTracking: false,
    shadow: false, 
    animation: false
  }
},
```

****Note : check if you already set plotOptions in another part of your chart, if you already did just add the lines to the existent plotOptions , if you write it twice it wont work.***

3.- Add HTML structure to the layout html file, remember that wicked_pdf can't see your assets pipeline.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD> scripts </HEAD>
<BODY> charts and text </BODY>
</HTML>
```

4.- Include both internal and external JS files (include CSS files if you have) in the PDF layout view (HEAD tag), in my case I used js files to store my chart templates and generate dynamic charts like this :

```
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js" integrity="sha256-36cp2Co+/62rEAAYHLmRCPIych47CvdM+uTBJwSzWjI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/heatmap.js"></script>
    <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "chart_templates/chart_bar_combined" %>
```

Hope it helps, this answer combines some short and less explained solutions.

Regards

Comment: If this doesn't work for you, check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53008582/1296209